# Que significa el %g en Java

Tags: java, formato

Que significa el %g en java, el profesor no me lo quiere explicar y quiere que lo busque por mi cuenta, pues aquí estoy.

Comment: Es una conversión a coma flotante, usando la notación que requiera menor espacio. Buscando un poco en [google](https://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/input_output_printf_es.html) se ve rápido

Comment: Un consejo que espero no tomes a mal: En realidad lo que te dijo es `buscar`, no `pregunta en un foro`.Tu primera opción siempre debe ser un buscador y la ultima un foro. Si cuando te dicen `busca` y lo primero que haces es ir a un foro creo que muestra un alto nivel de desidia y no habla bien de ti como gente de sistemas, informática o computación.

Comment: Hola @script12 bienvenido al sitio, aquí es recomendable investigar y agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, esto para que tus preguntas tengan buena recepción en el sitio y obtengas la ayuda deseada, es importante revisar [ask]. Te sugiero también revisa [tour] para entender el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos y bienvenido.

Comment: que tal si nos muestra lo que buscastes , que no comprendistes! asi te podemos ayudar mejor ademas de que tu pregunta puede ser canonica y muy util a la comunidad , ¿por cierto ya hicistes el [tour]?

Answer (score 0):

Es un ["especificador de formato"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

En este caso `%g` se aplica a un  número decimal de coma flotante, es similar a `%f` que se aplica también a un  número decimal de coma flotante y da como salida un numero decimal, pero en el caso de `%g` puede dar una salida en notación científica o formato decimal dependiendo de la precisión y el valor.

> [**%g**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) El resultado se formatea usando notación científica computarizada o
>   formato decimal, dependiendo de la precisión y el valor después del
>   redondeo.

Ejemplo imprimiendo el valor de la constante [PI (π)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_%CF%80):

```
   Formatter fmt = new Formatter();   
   System.out.println(fmt.format("Valor de PI = %g", Math.PI));
```

Salida:

```
Valor de PI = 3.14159
```

Esta es una lista de los especificadores usados en Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa :

[Formateo de cadenas en Java](http://mundogeek.net/archivos/2009/05/17/formateo-de-cadenas-en-java/)

Comment: una buena respuesta para una mala pregunta :(

Comment: @JackNavaRow ya votaste a cierre?

Comment: si señor! :(, la verdad tu respuesta me gusta porque todas estas especificaciones aplican para muchos lenguajes, pero a la pregunta le falta!, vale la quitare esperando que el OP me reponda el comentario